# Is it possible to use GridLayout(or TableLayout) and a Relative Layout Together?

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout, grid-layout

I am developing an android app and in the app I plan to cover an image with a gridlayout of buttons. I can display the image using an ImageView, but I can't seem to find a way to cover the image with a grid of buttons. So far I could have a grid of buttons, but the image would be in a grid as well when I want it beneath the grid. Is there a way so that I can cover the image with the grid of buttons? Thanks in advance, also let me know if I was too vague, I've had a hard time articulating my questions here.

Comment: If you're asking about adding one of them as a child of the other, then there is no problem.

Comment: I'm still a little new to android dev, but when you say adding one as the child of the other, would that be making the grid layout a child of the relative so that I could layer them?

Comment: exactly, or the other way around. layouts are like any other view for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and with something like this, an image of what you want would be helpful. However, it sounds like you want an image as the background with `Button`s on top of this image.

For this, you can use whichever `ViewGroup` works best for what you need (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc...) and make the background the image you need.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/myImage"/>   <!-- where myImage is the image you
                                                  want as your background -->
```

Then use your `GridLayout` or whatever you want to use as a child of the `ViewGroup` you used as your root `ViewGroup`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/myImage"/>   <!-- where myImage is the image you
                                                  want as your background -->
    <GridLayout
          .../>
```